# Cookies are not set in production env. (Nodejs, angular)

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, angular, cookies

I am working on my app and I have an issue with cookies. To be more specific - cookies are probably not send from an iPhone (chrome, safari).

Wierd part is that when I open my app on any other device (in production) everything works nice as I expect. Only on iPhone, cookies are not send with each request (I can see in the logs, that cookie object is null).

When I open my app on PC and inspect cookies in chrome dev tool, they are not there, but when I ran my app on dev server, everything works just fine and even cookies are in the dev tools.

Also, I am getting this warning in chrome, but i don't know if this has any association with my problem.

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at domain.com was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.

Do you have any idea, why this is happening? 
Thanks for your advices

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cookies are set into different domain (Node.js, Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59141269/cookies-are-set-into-different-domain-node-js-angular)

Comment: No, this question was actually asked by me... :D