# Cookies are set into different domain (Node.js, Angular)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I am doing web app using Angular and Node.js (Express) and I have a problem with cookies - they are set into my backend domain instead of my frontend.

When I make a `POST request` to `/auth endpoint`, server will return HttpOnly cookies - one is JWT and the second is refresh token. When I inspect network tab in chrome, I can see that server sent these cookies back, but when I inspect Application > Storage > Cookies, nothing is here.

I find out, that cookies are set on my backend domain. *(app-backend.com* instead of *app.com)* They are just simply associated with my backend domain.

Wierd thing is, that my app is working just fine on my computer, but when I switch to my phone, cookies are not sent from there (I am using iPhone with Safari or Chrome). Also, when I ran my app on localhost dev server, everything worked aswell.

I tried to set domain in cookie config to my frontend domain, it is not working at all.

Also, Chrome warns me with this message, I don't know if it has anything to do with my problem

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at "my-domain" was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Here is my code on github:

Frontend: https://github.com/TenPetr/dashboard

Backend: https://github.com/TenPetr/dashboard_backend

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: You can not set cookies for arbitrary domains. If your POST request goes to `app-backend.com`, then the server can only set a cookie for that in the response - not for `app.com`.

Comment: aah.. understand. And do you know how its posible that this works on computer?
Or do you have any idea, how can I set these cookies on app.com domain?

Comment: btw. I am using Heroku for both frontend and backend

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `SameSite=None; Secure` attributes in your [`production.json`](https://github.com/TenPetr/dashboard_backend/blob/2948868ed054cf405a9804febba6121b4cb01c5d/config/production.json#L2) which is correct. However, depending on your version of iOS / Safari you may be hitting [an incompatibility issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198181) where the cookies are incorrectly treated as `SameSite=Strict`.

In your development set-up you are both: not setting `SameSite=None; Secure`, and might be using URLs that count as the same site anyway, e.g. serving on `localhost` can lead to some weird cookie behaviour.

I would try testing your production configuration without the `SameSite=None` attribute. If this then starts to work on Safari, then you are hitting that bug. You can mitigate this by either setting two versions of the cookie, or adding useragent sniffing. There are more details on https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes

Alternatively, you may be hitting [Safari cookie policy issues](https://webkit.org/blog/9521/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-3/) if you are attempting to set cookies from the back-end server when it's not a site the user actually visits.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I think that I am hitting the last one, because as I said, everything worked on Android and PC but only on iPhone, I had these troubles. Wierd part is that it started to work in one moment, but only on Safari - Chrome didnt work.
Do you have any recomendation, link or something how to properly set these cookies when my frontend and backend are on different domain? (But still both on heroku). I didnt find anything, thanks a lot!

Comment: And basically, If I understand well.. I cant set cookies from backend.app-heroku.com to frontend.app-heroku.com, right?

Comment: Potentially look for ways to make those requests between the front and back end not cross-site, e.g. hosting on `a.example.com` and `b.example.com`. Alternativel maybe hosting the front-end code from the back-end project?

Comment: I will take a look if there is a way to host multiple apps on Heroku on one domain. Then, it should work...